# Не могу считать значение ключа реестра

Tags: c++, реестр

Есть ключ в реестре:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Posix\NetStat

А у ключа есть значение

> Downloaded
>   типа `REG_SZ` со значением `done`

Пытаюсь считать его значение. Ничего не выходит.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    ULONG result;
    DWORD sz = 1024;
    // open section and get hKey handler
    result = RegOpenKeyExA(
        hKey,
        "Software\\Posix\\NetStat",
        0,
        REG_SZ,
        &hKey);
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "Can't open section" << endl;
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    // get desired value
    result = RegGetValueA(
        hKey,
        "Software\\Posix\\NetStat",
        "Downloaded",
        RRF_RT_ANY,
        NULL,
        (LPDWORD)buf,
        &sz);
    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "Can't get value of Downloaded" << endl;
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

После выполнения первой функции `result` равен 0. То есть первая функция работает.
После выполнения второй функции `result` равен 2.

> `#define ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND             2L`

Разумеется никакого значения функция в `buf` не возвращает..
Вот ссылка на описание функции на MSDN. Только там `RegGetValue()`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Разрядность ОС и разрядность приложения какие?

Comment: ОС х64. Приложение х86

Comment: Значит это Registry Redirector (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx), по ссылке можно прочитать что делать

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, прочитал, но не понял что делать.. Попробовал флаги менять - не помогает. Английский не в совершенстве знаю

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, там написано, что эти флаги надо указывать в параметрах первой функции `RegOpenKeyExA`, но и так ничего не работает. А именно, если указать `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` в параметре первой функции, то и она возвращает ошибку. 5L

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74565/discussion-between--and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема у вас, по всей видимости, тут:

```
result = RegOpenKeyExA(
    hKey,
    "Software\\Posix\\NetStat",
    0,
    REG_SZ,
    &hKey);
```

В частности `RegOpenKeyExA` изменяет значение `&hKey`. Более того, использовать `RegOpenKeyExA` вообще не имеет смысла, так как она просто открывает ключ в реестре, а вам нужно прочитать значение. И, как писали в комментариях выше, в документации есть флаг [`RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx). Вот рабочий пример:

```
RegGetValueA(
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
    "Software\\Posix\\NetStat", 
    "Downloaded", 
    RRF_RT_ANY | RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY, 
    NULL, 
   (LPDWORD)buf, 
    &sz
);
```

Вызывать `RegCloseKey` по всей видимости, тоже не нужно.

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает также. Возвращает `2L`

Comment: Покажите код, как вы используете флаг. Прям все аргументы функции RegGetValueA. Особенно первый

Comment: я взял и скопировал сейчас Ваши два параметра вместо `RRF_RT_ANY` в своем коде. Остальное без изменений

Comment: Обратите внимание на первый аргумент, в частности на hKey. Не зря он в первую функцию по ссылке передается

Comment: Я так и делаю. Передаю по ссылке. В первой функции получаю это значение в него, а во второй его же и вставляю `hKey`. Не правильно ?

Comment: Нет, `RegOpenKeyExA` его  изменяет. И там вообще нужно что-то другое передавать ...A pointer to a variable that receives a handle to the opened key....

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74566/discussion-between--and--).

Comment: Смотрите апдейт

Comment: спасибо, уже прочитал. Меняю параметры первой функции, но пока безрезультатно.

Comment: Тебе вообще не нужна первая функция

Comment: Разобрался, Большое спасибо.